# Getting device orientation (yaw, roll and pitch) in Flutter

Tags: android, rotation, flutter, sensors, gyroscope

In Android I can get the device yaw, roll and pitch using a `GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor.

I need to do the same thing in Flutter, but I haven't been able to find anything but the [sensors](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sensors) package, which only gives access to accelerometer & gyroscope sensors.

What can I do? Do I need to calculate the orientation myself from the accelerometer and gyro?

Comment: You could use `plaform_channel` to call android methods and fetch the result from flutter

Comment: @RémiRousselet Can I do the opposite? Like call Flutter functions from Android? Because that will solve my problem better

Comment: Yes, see [How to call methods in Dart portion of the app, from the native platform...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if this is still relevant, as the question wasn't closed, but for those seeking the answer... there is now a [Flutter Sensors package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sensors) which does all the magic for you.

You'll have to subscribe to the streams to get the current values of the accelerometers and gyroscopes, of course.

For example:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamSubscriptions
        .add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _accelerometerValues = <double>[event.x, event.y, event.z];
      });
    }));
    _streamSubscriptions.add(gyroscopeEvents.listen((GyroscopeEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _gyroscopeValues = <double>[event.x, event.y, event.z];
      });
    }));
    _streamSubscriptions
        .add(userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _userAccelerometerValues = <double>[event.x, event.y, event.z];
      });
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the yaw (Azimut) is not available with this package

Comment: Umm, Yaw is the Z axis. (Y - Pitch, X - Roll)

Comment: Sorry I was talking about https://github.com/aeyrium/aeyrium-sensor/ package, concerning the 'sensors' package, it's not very handy as you can only get a delta and not current values at a time, which means that you have to track values from a starting 'basis' position, which is not the case with the aeyrium-sensor package but which unfortunately lacks the yaw value.

Comment: From what the documentation says about the Flutter package, these are "current" values of acceleration. Not deltas. For example: "Acceleration force along the x axis (including gravity) measured in m/s^2."

See more here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/lib/sensors.dart

Answer (score 3):

I would not use the Flutter `sensors_plus` package to get yaw, roll or pitch. Even if you only wanted  **yaw** (aka. heading or azimuth), as shown in this [Github issue: MagnetometerEvent to compass values](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/903). It is challenging to convert magnetometer readings (microteslas) into roll, pitch, yaw because of the maths. You only get raw magnetometer readings.

As I wrote in the [comment](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/903#issuecomment-1290281338) there:

> I would highly recommend using
> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass, https://pub.dev/packages/motion_sensors or writing your own plugin to
> use the OS APIs to get the data you need directly, instead of using
> the magnetometer readings (unit: micro Teslas), to allow you to use the
> operating-system calculated heading, which could use multiple
> sensors (sensor fusion) to give improved accuracy based on the
> hardware, as well as compensate for the location (the magnetometer
> only allows you to calculate magnetic north, not true north).

- `motion_sensors` provides an [`OrientationEvent`](https://pub.dev/documentation/motion_sensors/latest/motion_sensors/OrientationEvent-class.html), which contains roll, pitch and yaw, in radians.

---

### Writing your own plugin

If you need roll or pitch (more than yaw/heading/azimuth), the OS APIs provide it:

- On Android, in Java from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25972519/7365866):

```java
                float orientationData[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientationData);
                azimuth = orientationData[0];
                pitch = orientationData[1];
                roll = orientationData[2];
```

- On iOS, in Swift, from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764368/7365866)

```swift
CMQuaternion quat = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
myRoll = radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z)) ;
myPitch = radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z));
myYaw = radiansToDegrees(asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z));
```

Answer (score 0):

compass_plus 0.0.4,This works for me